# Select dropdown option and display table (javascript)

Tags: javascript

With a SELECT query I obtain an array of 7 names, create a dropdown list and each name is a table which is then hidden.
I want to click on the name in the dropdown list and display the table.
I am not receiving any errors but the following code only displays the first table in the array no matter what option is selected. I have little knowledge of javascript and the function has been cobbled together from various queries on the site.
Javascript:

```
function changeOpt(clicked) {
var x = document.getElementById("optChange");
var optVal = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
for(var i =0; i<x.length;i++){
if(optVal = document.getElementById('datath'))
document.getElementById('data').style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

HTML/PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$array = $row;                                                                          
//echo '<pre>'.print_r($array).'</pre>';
echo '<table id="data" style="display:none;">';
echo '<tr><td>You searched for:</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><th id="datath">'.$row[0].'</th><th>'.$row[1].'</th><th>'.$row[2].'</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';


$option .= '<option value = "'.$row['1'].'">'.$row['1'].'</option>';
    }


?>
<form method="post" action="#" id="my_form" >  
<select id="optChange" name="opt" onchange="changeOpt(this.id)">
<option><--select a name--></option>
<option><?php echo $option; ?></option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" > 
</form>
```

Am I completely off-beam ? Can someone give me some guidance please to get my code straight.

Comment: can you provide the generated html without the php. Currently it looks like the php is going to put an option inside an option: <option ...><option></option></option>. You're html looks broken before you've even begun to look at the javascript.

Comment: Without the php the output is the text input with a (!)Notice: undefined variable: option.........at line 53 ( which is the line <option><?php echo $option;?></option>).